# java game абстрактный класс

Tags: java, разработка-игр, awt

Как мне сделать абстрактный класс, который будет реализовывать их методы и создавать 2 и более объектов, которые впоследствии нужно внести в список? Не расписывайте словами, как это сделать, в теории я знаю, на практике реализовать не могу! Кому нетрудно, разжуйте бестолковому студенту все до мелочей, ибо сколько я не пытался, выходят только одни ошибки.

**Для примера, вот первый класс:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class BasicEnemy extends GameObject {

    private Handler handler;

    public BasicEnemy(float x, float y, ID id, Handler handler) {
        super(x, y, id);
        velX = 5;
        velY = 5;
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds(){
        return new Rectangle((int)x,(int) y, 16, 16);
    }

    public void tick() {
        x += velX;
        y += velY;
        if(y <= 0 || y >= Game.HEIGHT - 48) velY *= -1;
        if(x <= 0 || x >= Game.WIDTH - 20) velX *= -1;
        handler.addObject(new Trail(x, y, ID.Trail, Color.red, 16, 16, 0.02f, handler));
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect((int)x, (int)y, 16, 16);

    }
}
```

**И второй:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class SmartEnemy extends GameObject {

    private Handler handler;
    private GameObject player;

    public SmartEnemy(int x, int y, ID id, Handler handler) {
        super(x, y, id);
        this.handler = handler;
        for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
            if(handler.object.get(i).getId() == ID.Player) player = handler.object.get(i);
        }
    }
    public Rectangle getBounds(){
        return new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, 16, 16);
    }

    public void tick() {
        x += velX;
        y += velY;
        float diffX = x - player.getX() - 8;
        float diffY = y - player.getY() - 8;
        float distance = (float) Math.sqrt((x-player.getX())*(x-player.getX()) + (y - player.getY())*(y-player.getY()));

        velX = (float) ((-1.0/distance) * diffX);
        velY = (float) ((-1.0/distance) * diffY);

        if(y <= 0 || y >= Game.HEIGHT - 48) velY *= -1;
        if(x <= 0 || x >= Game.WIDTH - 20) velX *= -1;

        handler.addObject(new Trail(x, y, ID.Trail, Color.green, 16, 16, 0.02f, handler));
    }
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect((int)x, (int)y, 16, 16);
    }
}
```

**Методы у них одинаковые, нужен абстрактный класс!
Ранее они создавались подобным образом:**

```
handler.addObject(new BasicEnemy(r.nextInt(Game.WIDTH - 50), r.nextInt(Game.HEIGHT - 50), ID.BasicEnemy, 5, 5, handler));
```

**Сам класс handler, который вносит в список:**

```
package com.wavegame.main;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Handler {

    LinkedList<GameObject> object = new LinkedList<GameObject>();

    public void tick(){
        for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);
            tempObject.tick();
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics g){
        for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);
            tempObject.render(g);
        }
    }

    public void clearEnemys(){
        for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);
            object.clear();
            if (Game.gameState != Game.STATE.End)
            addObject(new Player((int)tempObject.getX(), (int)tempObject.getY(), ID.Player, this));
        }
    }
    public void deleteEnemy(ID id){
        for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);
            if(tempObject.getId() == id){
                removeObject(tempObject);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean objectAmountFrom2To4(ID id){
        int amount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);
            if (tempObject.getId() == id){
                amount++;
            }
        }
        if (amount > 2 && amount < 4){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean checkNotEnough(ID id){
        int amount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);
            if (tempObject.getId() == id){
                amount++;
            }
        }
        if (amount < 2){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void addObject(GameObject object){
        this.object.add(object);
    }

    public void removeObject(GameObject object){
        this.object.remove(object);
    }

}
```

**И класс GameObject, который наследуют противники:**

```
package com.wavegame.main;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public abstract class GameObject {

    protected float x, y;
    protected ID id;
    protected float velX, velY;

    public GameObject(float x, float y, ID id){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public abstract void tick();
    public abstract void render(Graphics g);
    public abstract Rectangle getBounds();

    public void setX(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }
    public void setY(int y){
        this.y = y;
    }
    public float getX(){
        return x;
    }
    public float getY(){
        return y;
    }
    public void setId(ID id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public ID getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public void setVelX(int velX){
        this.velX = velX;
    }
    public void setVelY(int velY){
        this.velY = velY;
    }
    public float getVelX(){
        return velX;
    }
    public float getVelY(){
        return velY;
    }
}
```

**___________________________________________________
UPDT:**

В данном случае, фабричный метод работает замечательно, еще раз спасибо за него, но мне нужно использовать абстрактный класс для создания объектов и добавления в сам игровой процесс, каким образом это сделать? Абстрактный класс создан, а смысла его использования здесь не вижу, но он конкретно мне требуется, не могли бы расписать, как его применить? Все данные, необходимые для работы, приведены выше.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public abstract class Enemy extends GameObject {
//all other enemies extends "Enemies"!!!!!!!!!
    public Enemy(float x, float y, ID id) {
        super(x, y, id);
    }
    public abstract void tick();
    public abstract Rectangle getBounds();
    public abstract void render(Graphics g);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, как при помощи абстрактного класса вы хотите создавать объекты. Он сам по себе ничего не в состоянии создать.

Как вариант, можете воспользоваться шаблоном `фабричный метод`:

```
enum EnemyType {
    SMART,
    BASIC
}

abstract class Enemy extends GameObject {
    //реализация или определение общих методов
}

class SmartEnemy extends Enemy {
}

class BasicEnemy extends Enemy {
}


final class EnemyFactory {
    private EnemyFactory() {
    }

    public static Enemy create(EnemyType type) {

        switch (type) {
            case SMART:
                return new SmartEnemy();
            case BASIC:
                return new BasicEnemy();
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("type is wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за шаблон, но у меня такая проблема, что при создании абстрактного класса, я вношу туда метод:
public abstract void render(Graphics g);
А при вызове этого метода через абстрактный класс, например:
AbstractEnemy enemy;
enemy.render(сюда он просит передать Graphics g);
Компилятор ругается на любой аргумент, кроме null, как с этим бороться?

Comment: Мне как раз-таки нужна //реализация или определение общих методов , а желательно еще как их и использовать

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, у вас есть GameObject, аналогично сделайте с классом Enemy. Польза от абстрактного класса и от наследования  в целом, это уменьшения дублирования кода, путем выноса общих методов в класс родитель. Если у вас такого кода нет, но вам хочется сделать разбиение на сущности, то используйте интерфейсы.

Comment: Приведите код, с методом не принимающим ничего кроме null

Comment: Посмотрите обновление моего поста.

Comment: @StabOnes можете в абстрактный класс вынести реализацию методов render и getBounds и не реализовывать их в классах потомках, т.к. тут на лицо дублирование кода.